# Java. io. Socket. Почему не работает передача stream от сокета

Tags: java, сокет, io

Строка прочитанная у клиента должна передаваться серверу по сокету, но не передается, не могу понять почему.

Вот код:

Клиент:

```
public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Client().startClient();
    }

    private Socket socket;

    private void connections() {
        try {
            this.socket = new Socket("localhost",5000);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void startClient() {
        this.connections();

        try (InputStream in = this.socket.getInputStream();
             OutputStream out = this.socket.getOutputStream()) {

            String command = this.sendMassage(out);

            while (!"q".equals(command)) {
                System.out.println(command);
                out.flush();
                command = this.sendMassage(out);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private String sendMassage(OutputStream out) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader readCons = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        BufferedWriter send = new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(out,"UTF8"));

        String command = readCons.readLine();
        send.write(command);
        return command;
    }
}
```

Сервер:

```
public class Server {

    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private Socket socket;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Server().startServer();
    }

    private void initServerSocket() {
        try {
            this.serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5000);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void socketAccept() {
        try {
            this.socket = this.serverSocket.accept();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void startServer() {
        this.initServerSocket();
        System.out.println("Wait...");
        this.socketAccept();
        System.out.println("ok");
        String massage;

        try (InputStream in = this.socket.getInputStream();
             OutputStream out = this.socket.getOutputStream()) {

            massage = this.getMassage(in);

            while (!"q".equals(massage)) {
                System.out.println(massage);
                massage = this.getMassage(in);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private String getMassage(InputStream in) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(in,"UTF8"));

        return br.readLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы на Вашем месте использовал **DataInputStream/DataOutputStream**, у Вас что-то с отправкой с клиента.
Если замените на клиенте на:

```
private String sendMassage(OutputStream out) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader readCons = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String command = readCons.readLine();
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(out);
        dos.writeUTF(command);
        return command;
}
```

А на сервере на:

```
private String getMassage(InputStream in) throws IOException {
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(in);
        return dis.readUTF();
}
```

Должно взлететь

Comment: Спасибо! Действительно взлетело. Странно что без дата обертки не хотело... Магия...

Comment: @Павел Никакая не магия. Просто `BufferedWriter`, как следует из названия, буферизует вывод, а не передаёт его сразу. Да и перенос строки вы не пишете, чтобы потом `readLine()` его прочитал.

Comment: Ок понял спасибо за пояснения. Буду иметь это в виду.